# 19th century Latin species description

Tags: taxonomy, history

While reading a 19th century text of new species description, I'm confused by some Latin phrases.

The case here is:

> Corp. long. 8 poll., caud. 9 poll.

I guess 'corp.' and 'long.' are abbreviations of some Latin terms, and the whole meaning of the combination of these two words is probably "body length". But I still can't figure out what "caud." and "poll." (the number seems like is in inch though) are stand for.

The species described is a rodent species. Full text could be found [here](http://biodiversitylibrary.org/page/28500480) (p.185).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Caud." refers to the tail (lat: cauda) and, judging from the description, "poll." seems to be another word for inch. So the translation should be something like:

Body length: 8 inches, tail length: 9 inches.

Answer (score 12):

The *pollex* was a [Roman length measurement](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Roman_units_of_measurement#Length), approximately equivalent to an inch. The *pollex* was also known as the *uncia*, which is where the word "inch" comes from. There were 12 *unciae* in a *pes* ...

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation. Sorry don't have enough rep to upvote.